# If shirk comes through waswaas, do we get accountable for it?

Tags: waswasa

Assalamu Alaikum Warahmatullahi Wabarakatuhu,

I know that if waswaas of a bad thought is something you dont get accountable for. But what if it's about shirk thoughts?
Also how do you know if a thought is from yourself or shaytaan?

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu Alaikum Warahmatullahi wabarakatuhu

All praise is due to Allah , lord of the heavens and the hearth . I bear witness that there is absolutely no god other Than Allah SWT and that prophet Muhammed SAW is the slave/servant of Allah and Allah’s final messanger

Selam brother , first I would like to say that shirk thoughts do not count as long as you do not believe in them in your heart or you don’t say it with your tounge. However you should also try to avoid it as much as you can . No matter what thought goes through your head , that is not a sin and plus Allah the most Merciful will even reward you for that . But however if you believe it in your heart and you like it , then it is accountable. Regarding your second question brother , you would know that your thoughts are wasawas if your heart doesn’t like it and if you firmly believe in your shirk thoughts. However , if you cannot control these thoughts then you won’t be accountable for that because Allah SWT says that no soul will be burdened by him from what his servant cannot bear.

So to sum it all up , as long as you don’t believe in them your ok . And if you do not like them then it is 99% wasawas . But Allah knows  best . I ask Allah to help you with your thoughts brother . Plus I also get these shirk thoughts aswell but Alhamdulillah they have gone so much easier . Always make dua brother Allah won’t reject you . Assalamu Alaikum Warahmatullahi WabaraKatuhu.

Answer (score 0):

Just thoughts won't make you kafir or sinful as long as you don't believe them or do anything according to those thoughts.But you must try to avoid them.Keep yourself busy in useful works or anything you like to do,which makes you happy and positive,worldy or religous or both.Listen and read Quran.And Ask Allah to help you.InshaAllah it'll be fine.